# Upload resized image (by flash) to servlet

Tags: flash, servlets, file-upload

How can I read a JPEG image in Servlet when I resize&upload it using Flash?

I have it in my `doPost()` method, but I cannot find the file. I cannot get it by `request.getParameter(...)`.

When I get it with `request.getInputStream()` and write it to a file, then I cannot open it. Somehow the JPEG encoding is corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File upload requests over HTTP are usually sent using `multipart/form-data` request encoding and **not** using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding as you seem to expect with your `getParameter()` attempt. The `getInputStream()` gives you the *entire* request body, which is also not what you want. You basically need to parse it into useable parts and extract the uploaded file from it.

If you're already on Servlet 3.0 (which is already out for almost 3 years), then just use `getPart()` instead.

```
Part uploadedFile = request.getPart("fieldName");
InputStream uploadedFileContent = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
// Now just write it to an arbitrary OutputStream the usual way.
```

Or if you're still on Servlet 2.5 or even older, then grab [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload).

#### See also:

- [HTML specification chapter 17.13.4 - Form content types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) - describes the different form encoding types
- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) - contains more concrete examples of how to process a `multipart/form-data` request in a servlet